# Deserialize JSON property in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a JSON file as such:

```
{
    "id1" : {
       ...
    },
    "id2" : {
       ...
    }
}
```

I am using `mapper.readerForUpdating(object).readValue(jsonFile)` and want the reader to read only the data corresponding to the id that `object`'s class has provided in an annotation. Is there a way to annotate `object`'s class with "id1" or something so that `mapper` will only read values from "id1"?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one simple solution if your **id1** is static. Create a wrapper class which contains one getter (and setter) corresponding to the field you want **and** ignore all the other properties as follows:

```
@JsonProperty("id1")
public MyBean getCustomId()
{
     ...
}

@JsonProperty("id1")
public void setCustomId()
{
     ...
}
```

Second option would be to use `@JsonSerialize`  and `@JsonDeserialize` annotations and write your customized logic.